# Using Sass + Compass + Blueprint in Rails 3.1 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, compass-sass, blueprint-css, css-frameworks

I am struggling **BIG TIME** with getting this framework set up correctly.  Has anyone successfully been able to get this working?  If so, I would love any and all feedback.  Thanks!

I'm following the instructions from http://compass-style.org/install/ and wondering where to put the files within the Rails 3.1 app: inside `app/assets/stylesheets` or keep it in `app/stylesheets` as it resides when installing compass?

Also, compass gives a set of instructions after `$ compass init rails . --using blueprint` below:

```
Now add these lines to the head of your layout(s):

%head
= stylesheet_link_tag 'screen.css', :media => 'screen, projection'
= stylesheet_link_tag 'print.css', :media => 'print'
/[if lt IE 8]
= stylesheet_link_tag 'ie.css', :media => 'screen, projection'
```

This looks like HAML (which I'm not familiar with).  I add these link tags using .erb instead and nothing seems to work.

Comment: http://metaskills.net/2011/05/18/use-compass-sass-framework-files-with-the-rails-3.1-asset-pipeline/ google is your friend

Comment: @iliacholy i've read this multiple times, no luck

Comment: you didn't mention that in your question. Or anything really. You need to tell us what problems you ran into.

Comment: @iliacholy your right, edited the post a bit

Comment: Are your styles compiling? You can try `compass watch`, which should show you errors.  You don't need the `.css` on the stylesheet names.

Answer (score 0):

Putting this into my config/application.rb worked for me:

```
config.sass.load_paths ||= []
config.sass.load_paths << "#{Gem.loaded_specs['compass'].full_gem_path}/frameworks/compass/stylesheets"
config.sass.load_paths << "#{Gem.loaded_specs['compass'].full_gem_path}/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets"
```

REF: https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/3